# How to structure the app which is built with angularjs, meteorjs, and ionic ?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework

Wanted to build a demo app for myself to learn how angularjs and meteorjs work together. what are the best practices for building full stack app using these three demanding technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Meteor app structure guideline: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html

If you are looking for the directory structure, find it here in the same document: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#javascript-structure

For practical example, see the app structure of sample app: https://github.com/meteor/todos